# How can i set a default value of an input of type text with Angular 4

Tags: angular

i want to set a default value for my text input in Angular 4 in order to persist the given string in a sql Database. I have used **value=" "** but it persist a **NULL** value in Mysql Database. This is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<label style="font-family: verdana">Titre:</label> 
<input style="font-size: 13px;" type="text" class="form-control"
id="libelle" name="libelle" value="bonjour" [(ngModel)]="bateau.libelle" #libelle="ngModel" required >
</div>
```

As shown in my code, it doesn't save the **bonjour** string in the database but a NuLL entry.
Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set it to your model, not to view layer - it will be reflected in input later on.
Do the following in `OnInit`

```
    ngOnInit(){
... whatever u are doing here
        this.bateau.lebelle='YourDefaultValue'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Antoniossss... but when i do as you said it give me an error like **cannot find name bateau** and when i add **this.bateau.libelle=...** the error disapears but the application start doing an infinite loading.

Comment: @ClémentBan-ñemII it should be with `this`. i just ommited it. Infinite loading is probably related  to something else..

Answer (score 0):

@Antoniossss Thanks i have find the solution like this:

-I have created a function **getValue**

```
getValue(bateau: Bateau) {
        bateau.libelle = 'bonjour';
      }
```

-Then i have called this function in **NgInit**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getValue(this.bateau);    
  }
```